# How to exclude Custom CSS from one page only

Tags: css, wordpress

I've read through some similar questions, but can't quite work it out ... I've got simple Custom CSS on my WordPress site to increase the space under lists:

```
ol, ul {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

How do I exclude page ID 10875 from having that Custom CSS applied?

Comment: Assuming your template puts the page ID into a class on the body element as usual, something like `body:not(.page-id-10875) ol, body:not(.page-id-10875) ul` should probably work.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from a body element in which the class is not `.page-id-10875` you can specify any nested element with `:is(<list of selectors>)` or `:where(<list of selectors>)` pseudoclasses, e.g.

```
body:not(.page-id-10875) :where(ul, ol) {
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Fabrizio! Unfortunately that had no effect.

Comment: Provide the actual code with the actual attribute on the body

Comment: Thank you Fabrizio. My page is here https://cell.bantergroup.com.au/sitemap/

Comment: it perfectly works, of course you need to remove your rule or it will be applied

Answer (score 0):

```
body:not(.exclude-page-id-class) ul,body:not(.exclude-page-id-class) ol {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sabih! Unfortunately that had no effect.

Comment: share demo example

Comment: Thank you Sabih. My page is here https://cell.bantergroup.com.au/sitemap/

Comment: comment this ol, ul {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
and add
body:not(.page-id-10875) :where(ul, ol) {
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}